# Doubt regarding android rosjava publishers and subscribers for sensor_msgs.imu

Tags: ros, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I am relatively new to the android and rosjava development environment. I am carrying out an experiment in which I am using the android_sensors_driver to publish the phone sensor readings to the master running on my Ubuntu PC. Now, I want to subscribe to the topic **/android/imu** (as published by the android_sensors_driver) carry out a couple of operations (**inside the phone**) and finally **re-publish the readings as /android/modified_imu**. Can someone please give me some advice on how to write the publisher and subscriber nodes? Can I somehow modify the pubsub tutorial for my purpose?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174795/doubt-regarding-android-rosjava-publishers-and-subscribers-for-sensor_msgs.imu/) by [Arjav](https://answers.ros.org/users/18918/arjav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just a quick response:

You would need rosjava to run everything on the phone. They have a pub/sub-Tutorial also. Basicly, you need to write one node, which subscribes to the **/android/imu** topic, just as described in the sub-tutorial. Instead of just printing it, you would then modify and publish it as described in the pub-tutorial to your desired topic.

You'll need to watch out for the message-types, since you aren't talking about strings anymore, but there is a section in the rosjava docs about how to use different message types.

Basicly: Go to the Rosjava documentation, follow their tutorials and in the end merge them to one node :)

Hope that helps,

Rabe

---

Originally posted by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) with karma: 683 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arjav](https://answers.ros.org/users/18918/arjav/) on 2014-06-24**:
Thanks a lot Rabe! I'll try that out.